# Add a menu to Google Drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm working on a project where my requirement is, when I share a file/folder to someone from Google Drive I should be able to attach a date to it, and once the date has passed they should not be able to view the file/folder.

When I was searching I stumbled upon http://ctrlq.org/code/19376-change-folder-permissions-google-script

My questions:
Is there a way I can activate this script on Google Drive itself, i.e. 
When a file is checked, I need a menu item saying 'Sharing Expires On' under the more options menu, and I should be able to add a date to it.

Please guide me through this.

Comment: If the response answers your question please use the "tick" option to mark that response as the answer. If not, you should edit your question and clarify it so people have an opportunity to give you a better answer.

Comment: I do not believe the question was answered. Presentation shows how to add Create or Open With menu item, not an arbitrary menu item

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's quite new and advanced (and neat) but in a nutshell you would:

1. Write an Apps Script using `DriveApp` and publish it as a web app.
2. Setup a new `Drive SDK` project on the developers console and point an `Open URL` action to the url from 1. This allows you to extend the context menu with your own "Expiring share" style option for a selected file(s).

There is a fantastic Google I/O 2013 session that covers this entire process: [Google I/O 2013 - Integrate Google Drive with Google Apps Script](http://youtu.be/0HVJMIeb3aE). When you watch it you'll see it starts out with a demo. The technical details diving into the above steps starts at 13:10.

Comment: @PeterSmith: Thanks a lot, let me go through this and keep this post updated if I'm able to achieve this.