# Is it possible to host a Google Drive app purely on Google Apps Script Web App?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm wanting to write a simple Google Drive app (that is triggered by right-clicking the file in Google Drive, then choosing "Open With"). All of the functionality of the app can be written in a Google Apps Script, and published as a web app. Is this a supported option?

In the API console, to enable Drive UI integration in this way, I need to add the URL to open files with, but need to verify that I own the site - how would I do this with a Google Apps Script?

Also, how would I go about registering/authorising the web-app with Drive so that it appears in the 'open with' menu?

Comment: Have you checked this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16691681/add-a-menu-to-google-drive)?

Comment: thanks @jess - I had not seen that. The video linked certainly seems to show it's possible, however, it doesn't go into any details on the authorization process, which is where I'm currently struggling, and I haven't been able to find any other examples of code which achieves this. Also, the video is quite old and uses the older style consoles and options.